# How do I split tmux in VMWare Fusion?

Tags: tmux

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 running inside VMWare Fusion.

I have installed tmux inside the guest OS.

Now, I want to split the terminal into two panes.

If I use the following options to split the terminals, it does not work:

```
Ctrl-a "          split vertically (top/bottom)
Ctrl-a %          split horizontally (left/right)
```

It appears that since I am pressing these key combinations inside the Guest OS, it may not be working properly.

So, is it possible to split the terminal window into panes inside the Guest OS?

Thanks.

Comment: The default command prefix for `tmux` is `Ctrl-b`, not `Ctrl-a`.  Have you configured `tmux` to use `screen` keybinds?

Comment: Other commands, like `prefix`+`c` work?